# Pass Variable Value as Argument to Command

Tags: bash, scripts, xdotool

I want to let `xdotool` type the current date automatically and wrote this bash script as a first try:

```
#!/bin/bash          
STR="Hello World!"
xdotool type $STR
```

Unfortunately, it already fails at this point. It just types ... something ... Something like "<[<[<" or "H[ll==]l{₁". Why is this? How do I make it type a string or the current date (format: `YYYY-MM-DD`, so today is `2016-01-06`)?

Comment: Strange, it works on my end. Can you do a quick test? Move your `~/.bashrc` e.g. to `~/.bashrc.bak`, copy a fresh `.bashrc` from `/etc/skel` to `~/`, start a new Bash instance (`exec bash`) and try again. Does that still happen?

Comment: Both the `.bashrc` in my home folder and the one in `/etc/skel` have the sha256sum `6fec775ff07e8424bbd774f8d6659dadfca37fd77ee66e2b9db92e3d045273ba`. So it doesn't work. My `.bashrc` file isn't even modified.

Comment: I just tested it on a virtual machine (not Ubuntu, though) and it really worked. But it doesn't on my actual system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash          
xdotool type `date +%Y-%m-%d`
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was this way but I wasn't able to remember it. But can you tell me why typing the content of the variable didn't work?

Comment: It works in a terminal window  but if I use it as a shortcut, (depending on the application) it either does nothing (GEdit), types some characters (it types `+%-%-%` into the dash), or has some other weird behavior (zooms out and kicks me out of the textarea I'm writing this in in Firefox).

Comment: I now accepted this as an answer because it works on my Ubuntu 16.04 system.

Answer (score 0):

I used `STR="Hello World!"  && xdotool type $STR` which seemed to work.  Not sure why yours didn't work. if you want to debug bash scripts you can use the shell built-in `set -xv` to get verbose details.

```
#!/bin/bash          
set -xv
STR="Good Bye Cruel World!"  && xdotool type $STR
```

Comment: It prints this: http://pastebin.com/ugE6C1Gg Which is ... kind of even more confusing, I guess ...